# AfterFx, crash when try run afterfx.exe -r

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I want to run a script load from location.
Same like:

`AfterFx.exe -r "demo.jsx"`

Content my file: `demo.jsx`

```
alert('hello world')
```

When i try to run script above:
[image]

But while I try to `-s` instance for `-r`, script run scucess

`AfterFx.exe -s "alert('hello world')"`

Can anyone guid me fix this error, i want to run script from local file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I finally resolve this error.
Use `-s` with `$.evalFile(URL-here)`

Full: `AfterFX.exe -s " $.evalFile("demo.jsx")"` ==> this work for me.